# Reference parent value

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way I can reference parent value, like per example

```
.btn-blue {
     background-color: $light-blue; 
     &:hover {
       background-color: rgba($light-blue,.7);
     }
}
.btn-green {
     background-color: $light-green;
     &:hover {
       background-color: rgba($light-green,.7);
     }
}
```

I would like to write one :hover selector which would get the value of the parent. Something like

```
.btn-blue {
     background-color: $light-blue; 
}
.btn-green {
     background-color: $light-green;
}
.btn-green, .btn-blue {
     &:hover {
           background-color: rgba($parent_color,.7);
     }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use mxins and pass the color in:

```
@mixin btn-color($selColor)
{ 
     background-color: $selColor; 
      &:hover {  background-color: rgba($selColor,.7); 
       } 
 }
```

And use it like so:

```
 .btn-green { @include btn-color($light-green); }
 .btn-blue { @include btn-color($light-blue); }
```